# ASP.NET site throws compilation error on webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

I am working on a webserver that has ASP.NET 2.0 as the activate instance of ASP.NET (I can't change it. I don't have control over it.)

I orginally wrote the site in 4.0, not even thinking to ask what version the webserver was in.  When it came to installing, I realized the error and changed the targeted framework. After a little bit of wrestling with VS 2010, it compiled fine.

I put it up, and now it is giving me this error:

[image: Error message]

Account used to be a .cs file, which I then put into it's own project so I could get in a DLL in hopes of it working with it being a dll.  It always fails when it comes to the first thing that references Account.

Account is compiled against .NET 2.0.

Any help? D:

Edit: The other important thing that may change this, is that the person is already hosting another ASP.NET site on the main folder.  He wants to host this site in a subfolder.

I have read that ASP.NET may not like that, so could that be the issue?

Comment: are you sure the `dll` is inside the site's `bin` folder?

Comment: Do you have a class named Account in a namespace named account. You shouldn't do that. See

Comment: Ehehe. yeah... It was sort of just a copy-and-paste from a .cs file which used to reside in the main project. Could that cause the issue?

Comment: I was supposed to paste a link. Here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: Sorry. I'm struggling with my phone, can't edit my previous broken comments. Anyway, Eric Lippert says you shuoldn't do that. So don't.

Comment: I renamed it so there is none of that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Check following:

1. Your application referencing assembly with Account class;
2. Corresponding assembly existing in web application 'bin' directory - you may referenced it, but not specified as 'copy always' in reference properties.
3. You built it, not just put into 'App_Code' (it is bad practice to put code in the App_Code for asp web application as I know)

Also, your error appeared only on 'production' host or reproduced also on VS devserver?

Comment: The assembly is being referenced.  I removed it, then re-added it to make sure.

I checked the /bin folder and the assemblies are most certainly in the folder.  

And I checked it on the VS devserver and it worked after changing global.asax from a public class to a public partial class.  I tried it again on the production host, and it still threw the same error.

Comment: The other important thing that may change this, is that the person is already hosting another ASP.NET site on the main folder.  He wants to host this site in a subfolder.  

I have read that ASP.NET may not like that, so could that be the issue?

Comment: What about local test? Whether your application starting siccesfully when you eight-clic it in Solution Explorer and choose 'Open in browser'?

Comment: Here is the odd part... It works on my local machine, it works on a seperate IIS instance on my machine, it works on a remote server under .NET 4.0 and .NET 2.0 Classic and Integrated.

I have no idea what is wrong with his server...